# Deploying Vue file in Express is not working as expected

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express

I am having one simple vue file (index.html)

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="example">
      <p>{{ hello }}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script>

        new Vue({
            el: '#example',
            data: { hello: 'Hello world!' }
        })
    </script>
```

When opening the index.html file in browser, it is printing `Hello world`. I need to deploy this in express server. Added server.js file as below,

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 1234;

// sendFile will go here
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started at http://localhost:' + port);
```

When running node server, browser is just rendering like below,

[image]

If I replace the `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` with `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>`, it is working fine. Dont know why it is not working when using Vue library as external file. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got it worked. Updated server.js as below, `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.get('/',function(req,res) {
    res.redirect('index.html');
})`

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line of code

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`
So you code would look like this

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 1234;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// sendFile will go here
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server started at http://localhost:' + port);
```